# What space does $n \times n$ matrix live in?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I was trying to solve this question

> 7. Find two linear operators $T$ and $U$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $TU = 0$ but $UT \neq 0$

There are infinite of these examples the first one that came to my mind $U(a,b) = (a+b,a+b)$ , $T(a,b)=(a-b ,a-b ) $

when I looked in the answers the answers consider $2\times 2 $ matrix!! which got me thinking is a $2 \times 2$ matrix even in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?and if not is it in $\mathbb{R}^4$ (since it has a dimension of 4 )? or what space does it lives in

Comment: A $2 \times 2$ matrix is an element of the space of all $2 \times 2$ matrices.  This is *isomorphic* to $\mathbb{R}^4$.  The matrix itself as a map would *act* on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Well, you wrote $U,V$ via their effect on a generic vector, but what do you think $U,V$ are?

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the space $\mathcal{M}(m\times n,\mathbb{R})$ of $m \times n$ real value matrices with $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. In general $\mathcal{M}(m\times n,\mathbb{K})\cong\mathbb{K}^{m\times n}$ for any field  $\mathbb{K}$.

To answer your question more precisely you can view a linear operator $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ as a $n\times n$ matrix so that $T(x)=Ax\;\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.